# Where can I find KML files for the North Sea?

Tags: kml

I need KML files (or something like this) for the North Sea. In a project group, we need to know where the navigational buoys are placed, in order to calculate routes for Offshore Windpark Servicing ships.

At http://map.openseamap.org/map/ I only found out that the map called 'ONC-NorthSea_GermanCoast12' is only available as a picture.

And the site http://www.freietonne.de/seekarte/ seems to have not as many
sea marks as the OpenSeaMap's maps.

But we need the positions of each buoy as a WGS84 coordinate for example. Is there any other source or way to obtain these information?

**Edit:**

Example for one ship route:

from 53.34N,7.20E Emden harbour

to 54.01N,6.60E Offshore windfarm "alpha ventus"

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to find the buoy station locations and identifiers. For Internet users, maps showing buoy locations are given at http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/. This provides a Google Map including the North Sea but there are links are bottom of page to get oberservations in KML format which includes list of some buoys world-wide. This is a good place to start.

An [updated list](http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/stndesc.shtml) of deployed buoys is available. Included in the description are their exact lat/lon location, the water depth, and the watch radius of the mooring.

An updated list of NDBC moored buoys and hull configurations is available in the [Weekly Platform Status Report](http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/wstat.shtml).

There is also http://www.nodc.noaa.gov/BUOY/

Comment: The websites you pointed me at only contain American buoys. I've downloaded the KML files and now have to search for anything in the above given coordinate area.